# Flutter pwa app no service worker detected

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I know that [flutter supports PWA](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-web-support-updates-8b14bfe6a908), but I can't enable it in my flutter web app. [My web app](https://ferraridamiano.github.io/ConverterNOW/#/) meet all the [requirements](https://web.dev/install-criteria/) for PWA support. But both chrome and edge doesn't display the install prompt. If I inspect the page I find the following message: "No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest". I have no experience in web programming.

Here's my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Converter NOW",
    "short_name": "Converter NOW",
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "minimal-ui",
    "background_color": "#0175C2",
    "theme_color": "#0175C2",
    "description": "A Unit and Currencies Converter. Converter NOW is immediate, fast and easy to use!",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "icons/Icon-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your service worker should be on your index.html If by any reason is not there, delete that file and use "flutter create ." to regenerate it.

Comment: BTW... your display should be "standalone" for PWA app-like UI. Will be better to delete the web folder and regenerate

Comment: Thanks @MarianoZorrilla, I tried to apply your suggestions but the result is the same. I also tried to copy/paste the index.html of flutter gallery (which is PWA) but nothing has changed :(

Comment: is your web hosted on a https server?

Comment: Yep! I use github pages and the site is forced to https

Comment: Yep! I use github pages and the site is forced to https

Comment: well... I've just visited your site and is trying to do PWA... but you're not using "display": "standalone" but if you do, remember that sites sometimes takes a bit to refresh.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried on a different project. Now I have updated also the main project (https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW). Re-deployed to gh-pages but nothing has changed :(

Comment: all I can see different from my projects is that your worker is not the same:

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }

and also the favicon rel <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

Comment: your addEventListener says 'load' and not 'flutter-first-frame' like mine

Comment: I also have <base href="/"> between line 3 and 4 of index.html

Comment: I discovered something strange. If I access the app with a local web server (such as dhttpd) the app is detected as PWA (the install banner appears), but if I put the same files on github the web app is not detected as PWA. I changed to flutter-first-frame, but if I also add <base href="/">, the site on github will not work, blank screen (but locally it works)

Comment: that's so weird... maybe github pages have limitations. Try surge.sh that is a free repo hosting, I use it for all my Flutter PWA ones

Comment: you're also using CanvasKit and not sure how that affects or not the PWA, but it shouldn't

Comment: On surge.sh it works! https://dry-ink.surge.sh/#/
It's a problem with github pages, but i know that someone managed to get it work also on gh pages, look here: https://kphanipavan.github.io/Time/#/
he inserted <base href="/Time/"> in the index.html. But I think there's more, if I try to to the same for my project it doesn't work on gh pages

Comment: I solved. Check the answer below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarianoZorrilla and [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68449) on Github I figured out what is the problem. Github pages and flutter PWA are not close friends. If you deploy to any other web server probably you will not find any kind of problem, just meet the [PWA requirements](https://web.dev/install-criteria/#criteria).
But if you want to deploy you PWA flutter app on ghpages you have to do the following:

1. Meet the [PWA requirements](https://web.dev/install-criteria/#criteria)
2. Add `<base href="/projectName/">` after `<head>` tag as shown [here](https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW/blob/4ecab5ff6985cf2e69bedb35cf3598b1c53c47c0/index.html#L4)
3. Comment `"/",` in flutter_service_worker.js file at about at line 50 as shown [here](https://github.com/ferraridamiano/ConverterNOW/blob/4ecab5ff6985cf2e69bedb35cf3598b1c53c47c0/flutter_service_worker.js#L50)

You need to do this because the PWA is not stored at root (`/`) but at `/projectName/`